# How to add Dependency Injection to IServiceCollection for nested generic constraint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

here is the ERROR code

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

// A<> is not right here
services.AddSingleton(typeof(I<>), typeof(A<>));

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

sp.GetRequiredService<I<W<int>>>();

public interface I<T> { }
public class W<T> { }
public class A<T> : I<W<T>> { }
```

I have some `A<T>` implemented `I<W<T>>`, but if I use the above approach it will try to initialize `A<W<T>>` for `I<W<T>>` but what I actually want is `A<T>`

---

Update 1:
If use

```
var interfaceType = typeof(I<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(W<>));
services.AddSingleton(interfaceType, typeof(A<>));
```

An exception is thrown when building the service provider

```
-       $exception  {"Cannot instantiate implementation type 'A`1[T]' for service type 'I`1[W`1[T]]'."} System.ArgumentException
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be something like
`services.AddSingleton(typeof(I<W<>>), typeof(A<>));`,
but that would not even compile. I think sou you need to put some variables in place

```cs
var interfaceType = typeof(I<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(W<>));
services.AddSingleton(interfaceType , typeof(A<>));
```

Comment: That would not work on building service provider.

```
$exception {"Cannot instantiate implementation type 'A`1[T]' for service type 'I`1[W`1[T]]'."} System.ArgumentException
```

Answer (score 0):

Itried with the codes and seems succeeded:

```
public class W<T> { }

public interface I<T>{ }
    
public class A<T>: I<T> where T : W<T> { }
```

In startup:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(I<>), typeof(A<>));
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: The exception would come up if you try to run IServiceProvider.GetService

Comment: Have you tried ( specific the type)serviceProvider.GetServices<....>();?